# Scraping the mp3 file from flash player after the conversion

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There is a `textarea` and a button `Synthesize` on a page.
It looks as follows:

```
        <textarea id="ttstext" name="text" style="font-size: 130%; width: 100%;
        height: 120px; padding: 5px;"></textarea>
        ...
        <div id="audioplayer">
            <script>
                create_playback();
            </script><audio autoplay="" autobuffer="" controls=""></audio>
        </div>
        <input id="commitbtn" value="Synthesize" type="submit">
```

When I click the button `synthesize`, the HTML code of the page will change as follows (It will create audio player).

```
<div id="audioplayer" style="display: block;"><embed width="370" height="20" flashvars="height=20&amp;width=370&amp;type=mp3&amp;file=http://services.abc.xyz.mp3&amp;showstop=true&amp;usefullscreen=false&amp;autostart=true" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" quality="high" name="mpl" id="mpl" style="undefined" src="/demo/mediaplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
```

I would like to generate the mp3 file from the Python code.

What I have tried so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "http://www..."

def textToSpeech():
  with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    try:
      browser.get(url)
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
      print "timeout"
    browser.find_element_by_id("ttstext").send_keys("Hello.")
    button = browser.find_element_by_id("commitbtn")
    button.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=100).until(
      lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('audioplayer'))
    src = browser.page_source
    return src

def getAudio(source):
  soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(source)
  audio = soup.find("div", {"id": "audioplayer"})
  return audio.string


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print getAudio(textToSpeech())
```

The key to success is to get the URL to the resulting mp3 file.
I don't know how to wait for the script to change the HTML (inner text of `<div id="audioplayer">`).
My code returns `None`, because it takes the result sooner.

Comment: Is the URL present in the `div` since the `div` shows up?

Comment: @Lawrence No. The URL with the mp3 file will be generated from the textarea after clicking the button `synthesize`.

Comment: And after the mp3 is created, which may take a long time, right?

Comment: @Lawrence It is usually a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of changes, it is not enough to wait for the element:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=100).until(
      lambda x: x.find_element_by_id('audioplayer'))
```

But you need to wait for it to change a certain condition, using `ExpectedCondition`. This is to get you started (not tested):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait_text = 'file=http://'
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"), wait_text)
    )
```

You can also checkout all expected conditions here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=text_to_be_present_in_element#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions

Comment: Now, it waits, but it will end with `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`. Are you sure the text is present in element? It is actualy a part of a parameter of a subelement.

Comment: I'm not sure, as I said, I haven't tested it. You need to figure out what text you are waiting for, I don't have a running example here.

Comment: I don't know where `text_to_be_present_in_element` is searching the wait_text. This didn't work. But it helped me to understand the logic. I tried the first waiting with `find_element_by_id('mpl')` and it works.